# Select statement with case condition to get values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have 3 columns to retrieve

```
Id  Happy       Sad     Angry

1      1        1       1

2      0        0       1

3      1        1       0
```

When I select all I want the output to be “Happy, sad,Angry” if the id is equal to one. 
My question is how do I have multiple case statement with different columns in one sql statement
Is it possible to retrieve multiple columns using case condition?

[image]

how to rename the column

Comment: What happens when the id is not equal to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select id,
       substring(concat(case when happy > 0 then ',Happy' else '' end,
                        case when sad > 0 then ',Sad' else '' end,
                        case when angry > 0 then ',Angry' else '' end
                       ), 2, 100) as newname
from t;
```

Some databases spell `substring()` as `substr()`.

Comment: seems like the column name is "no coloumn name" how can i set that coloumn name?

Comment: what does 2,100 means

Comment: Those are just used to get rid of the initial comma.  Depending on the database, there are lots of ways to do this.

Comment: Alright. May i know how can i name the column? because i need to call the column name in the datareader

Comment: Not only some databases, ANSI SQL has `substring()`!